# THREE.js WebGLRenderer canvas consumes 'click' mouse event

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I add the `domElement` (i.e. canvas) of the THREE.js `WebGLRenderer` to my document, the 'click' mouse event no longer fires when I click on the container element that is the parent of the canvas.

Is there a way of preventing the canvas from consuming mouse clicks?

**EDIT:** Removing the following single line of code (i.e. not adding the canvas at all) restores the click:

```
this.domElement.appendChild(this.threeRenderer.domElement);
```

Comment: WebGLRenderer by itself shouldn't affect any events. Are you by chance also adding an OrbitControls ?

Comment: @manthrax yes, using OrbitControls. They don't seem to intercept the click event, but the below solution breaks OrbitControls completely. Any ideas?

Comment: Make a copy of OrbitControls.js and modify it to do what you want. It's mostly designed for running as a full page app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possiblity would be to extend your CSS with `pointer-events:none` so that the canvas does not intercept mouse events that you're intending for the container element to consume:

**HTML**:

```
<!-- Your container element -->
<div id="container"> 

    <!-- The nested, child canvas used by THREE -->
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Prevent the canvas from intercepting mouse events */
#canvas {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
/* Register click event with the container element */
document.getElementById('container')
.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: @user2132190 didn't realise your were using orbit controls sorry!